# An arm for times of need. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> Tall and slender and sways like a swing
>
> Clears the sorrows of today and the tears of tomorrow
>
> A machete that makes a path so you can find your way
>
> A blade that doesn't cut, but isn't thrown away
>
> An arm that reaches, yet not far enough
>
> A prisoner hid from the sun to be left untouched
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe:

> Windshield Wiper Blade

Tall and slender and sways like a swing

> They're long and narrow and swing back and forth when used.

Clears the sorrows of today and the tears of tomorrow

> Maybe this is referring to rain? In which case, the wiper blades clear the rain from you path/sight.

A machete that makes a path so you can find your way

> Clears water and debris of the windshield so you can see.

A blade that doesn't cut, but isn't thrown away

> Called a blade, but doesn't cut like a knife per say. Also thought of: blades of grass, fan blade, roller blades etc.

An arm that reaches, yet not far enough

> Not sure. Usually wiper blades can only clear an arc on the windshield, but doesn't clear the edges and corners.

Like a prisoner behind bars, you're seen, never touched

> Again not sure, actually thought more of a fan for this one since the blades are usually caged. However, in this case the wiper blades are behind a shield/pane of glass where you can see them but can't touch them (at least when used as intended).

Comment: In case you care, I looked at this riddle again and decided to change the last line.  Your answer is still correct of course.

Comment: don't you technically dispose of those when you change them?

Comment: @visualnotsobasic but not because it doesn't (literally) cut, i guess.